# How to enable WCF traces programmatically?

Tags: wcf

Is there a way to enable/disable the WCF trace/logging for a perticular end point without changing the web.config ?

Comment: I think it isn't too much different than setting up other listeners but not 100%. If you examine: 

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36031/WCF-Tracing-FAQs#How can we enable tracing on the readymade tracing WCF objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to access the trace object by name, as its defined in the .config file. For example:

```
TraceSource ts = new TraceSource("System.ServiceModel");
```

Then you can set the filter level to all, none or anything in between:

```
ts.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.Off;   // nothing
ts.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.All;   // everything
ts.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.Warning;   //warning or higher
```

BTW - the `TraceSource` class is in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, so don't forget the appropriate `using` statement.

Comment: Where you want me to add this code ? in the service class itself ?

Comment: yes - the service class should have access to the trace objects.

Comment: Does now = not? And is that why you down-voted my answer? Perhaps you can elaborate on the problem, or start a new thread?

Comment: Does not works for me neither, the TraceSource works as I can Write in it but Wcf internals does not seems to take it into account.